# Facebook: visibility of posts with old dates

Tags: facebook

If I post a photo to Facebook and adjust the date so as to indicate that it is in the past, will this photo show up in my friends' timelines as any other recently posted photo would? Essentially what I want to do is sneak in a photo or two from a while back just to add to my profile, but not have it show up in my friends' feeds, and I was wonder if changing the date would accomplish this. If it doesn't, is there any way to make such a post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want add a photo and do not want to show it to your friends feed, change the audience settings. Choose **Only Me** option in audience selector and post. After sometime (say one day) you can change the audience and it will not show friends newsfeed until some activity will not happen on the post.

When we post a photo there is no option to change the date, but once it posted we can use *edit* button and change the date, description and location. But it will show in edited section and anyone can see what changes have made.